# Closing server with socket accepting clients

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to stop my server from accepting clients after 60 seconds,I have implemented the case when no one is connected to the server ,it stops after 60 second indeed via the `setSoTimeout` method,but how should I stop the server
60 seconds after someone connects?

```
public void start() {
    try {
        final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 50, address);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(60 * 1000);
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            final Socket newSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            final ClientContainer newClient = new ClientContainer(clientID.getAndIncrement(), newSocket);
            executorService.execute(new ClientContainerRunnable(newClient, this));
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("timeout expired");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent clients from connecting you could just close the server socket.  If you want this to occur 60 seconds after a client connects, you could use a scheduled executor service to schedule the closing of the server socket for 60 seconds in the future

```
 Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() -> serverSocket.close(), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```